# Prestashop 1.5 : Back office module with ajax calls

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am developing a Prestashop back office module in which the back end will respond to ajax calls . In a php file "/modules/mymodule/ajax/do-something.php" , How do I check that that the admin is logged in  ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
include_once('../../config/config.inc.php');
include_once('../../config/settings.inc.php');
include_once('../../classes/Cookie.php');

if( Context::getContext()->customer->isLogged() ) {
    // welcome
}
else{
    // please login  
}
```

As found in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616456/prestashop-session-cookies-login).