# Getting current Prestashop user in external site

Tags: codeigniter-2, prestashop-1.5

In order for me to get a Prestashop user's cart, I first need to know who the user is in my external CodeIgniter application.

I have tried various attempts like the following: http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/204227-webservice-and-check-if-user-is-logged-in/ and http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/156218-solvedish-integrating-prestashop-into-a-pre-developed-website/ and even [Prestashop: Session cookies & login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616456/prestashop-session-cookies-login) and http://webilyst.com/prestashop-cookie-structure/

But I could not get it working. For some reason, the moment I include config.inc.php, it redirects to the shop - instead of allowing me to get the ID required.

**My question: Any idea how to get this current user ID from PrestaShop in external epplication?**

**Edit 1**
I am using CI 2.1.4 and PrestaShop 1.5.6.x.

**Edit 2** Seems like the articles I have read is for an older version of PS. That code actually gets to a point where the Shop is being initialized, and once that is done, in Shop.php, the user is redirected to the shop. I do not want this to happen - I just want to find out who the current logged in user is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current customer ID with the following code:

```
include($prestashopBasePath . '/config/config.inc.php');
$context = Context::getContext();
$customerId = $context->customer->id;
```

The reason why you are redirected is that you execute the script from a URL that is different from the shop URL defined in back-office -> Preferences -> Set shop URL. For example the shop URL is example.com/presta and your script is in example.com/other/script.php.

The solution is to move your script to the PrestaShop directory.

Comment: thank you so much. My script is however a controller within CI, so not sure how to move my script.

Comment: I moved the code to a file called test.php in the shop directory, and then included that test.php in my script, and that did not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: I tried moving my shop into the CI directory, and that will overwrite the CI index.php, so that is not an option either. I thought that if I include() a file the included file is executed where it resides? For some reason, it appears not to be the case. It appears as if PHP reads the file, put the code in place where you called the include() file, and thus, the same happens as before. That is the only thing that makes sense to me. Although I knew it would most likely not work, I was desperate, so I also tried file_get_contents() and fopen()/fread(). Unsuccessful...

Comment: @Kobus Including test.php in CI will not work. Can you move CI inside the PrestaShop directory?

Comment: I will try, thanks, and let you know. Problem is that both have an index.php, and both need to be there. Perhaps put CI in subdirectory. I will post feedback.

Comment: @Kobus Yes, that is what I meant, putting CI in a subdir inside the PrestaShop dir.

Comment: Hi yenshirak. Thanks for all your help. I finally get the session data as needed. I need to hire someone like you! :-)