# Inisde prestashop create php/html BO page "secure". Module, token or?

Tags: php, html, prestashop

I created two files, an html and a php.
The first contains a simple form that passes the data to the php page that has to process them.
They connect to the PrestaShop database to retrieve various statistical information.

Only that creating these two simple files are not "protected".
That is, anyone knowing the name of the files and the path could open them and run it anywhere.

I would like them to be "internal" to the back office of PrestaShop, "protected", in security to avoid external access.

I hope I explained myself.
What road should I follow? Module? Use tokens?

I inserted

```
include_once('../config/config.inc.php');
include_once('../config/settings.inc.php');
include_once('../classes/Cookie.php');
$cookie = new Cookie('psAdmin');

if(!$cookie->isLogged()){
echo ("Please login");
exit;
}
else{
echo ("Logged in as: ".$cookie->customer_lastname." ".$cookie- 
>customer_firstname);
}
```

but it doesn't wors. I have white screen with "Please login"

Comment: You can allow access only for the admin using the cookie "psAdmin". like this but the cookie name is "psAdmin" instead of "ps". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616456/prestashop-session-cookies-login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a lot easier to create this form as a Module, more details of how to do that:
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/

By creating it as a module you can control permissions per Employees and it's available only in back-office by default.

I suggest you to put form inside `getContent` method and process Form using `postProcess` method. More on form creation:
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/adding-configuration-page/

You can find many examples of this in native modules like ps_imageslider, ps_newproducts with simple one input form etc.